# how to subtract 1 from a string which is a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, subtraction

Code example:

```js
var string = "7"
console.log(string - 1) // I would want to output 6.
```

The variable is a string since its taken from parsed html code, and subtract 1 for a 0 index character count.

Comment: Maybe **+string - 1** ?

Comment: Cast the string to a number. Either `Number(string)` or `+string`. However, I made a snippet out of your code, and it already outputs 6 (Javascript automatically casts `"7"` to `7`)

Comment: I didn't quite followed the question. The above snippet is producing expected o/p. If you subtract string from a number, JS will implicitly parsed them to correct type and execute the operation. What is your actual need? Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = "10" 
console.log(Number(a) - 1)   // output 9
```

Number() returns a number so you can either store it in a variable or directly subtract 1 from it

Answer (score 0):

First, cast the string to an integer using the parseInt() or Number() functions.
For your case, use parseInt(string, 10) or Number(string). You can set it equal to a new variable called num.
Then, simply just console.log(num-1). If you want, you can just console.log(parseInt(string, 10)-1) or console.log(Number(string)-1) directly.

Answer (score 0):

it's automatically done by javaScript.